# JavaScript: определение наведения путем координат

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Нужно решить сложный вопрос:
При наведении не на прямоугольный элемент, а на область в нем, нужно производить какое-либо действие. Вопрос в следующем - как это попроще реализовать? Допустим, у меня есть изображение:
http://uppix.com/f-2551440_conner_k50ed32f20011cd20.png
Оно с прозрачным фоном, при наведении на персонажа (именно на персонажа, а не на саму картинку), меняем, к примеру, фон бэкграунда. Т.е. надо построить сетку координат вокруг персонажа, а потом, если курсор внутри, то менять фон.

Comment: Решено. Спасибо за внимание)

Answer (score 1):

Я сделала цветок из иконок и задала им следующий код:

```
<img name="socializicon" src="img/icn/socializ-icon.png" width="117" height="128"  usemap="#m_socializicon" alt="" />
    <map name="m_socializicon" id="m_socializicon">
       <area shape="circle" coords="59,19, 16" href="http://www.reddit.com" title="Reddit" alt="Reddit" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="22,40, 16" href="https://www.yahoo.com" title="Yahoo" alt="Yahoo" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="22,80, 16" href="http://wordpress.org/" title="WordPress" alt="WordPress" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="59,104, 16" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_self" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="92,80, 16" href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_self" title="Youtube" alt="Youtube" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="91,40, 16" href="https://www.linkedin.com" title="LinkedIn" alt="LinkedIn" />
       <area shape="circle" coords="59,60, 16" href="https://plus.google.com" title="Google+" alt="Google+" />
    </map>
```